# Android App crash after modifying and reading data on two different fragments (firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, fragment

I'm having a crash that I'm struggling with since some time.

So here's my app, one fragment is here to had and remove a list of cars

This is the method used to print data in the first fragment :

```
void printData(View view){

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    final FirebaseUser FireUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(FireUser != null)
    {
        String uid = FireUser.getUid().toString();


        mDatabase.child("cars").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                Car car_db1 = dataSnapshot.child("car1").getValue(Car.class);
                Car car_db2 = dataSnapshot.child("car2").getValue(Car.class);
                Car car_db3 = dataSnapshot.child("car3").getValue(Car.class);
                Car car_db4 = dataSnapshot.child("car4").getValue(Car.class);

                mCarView1.setText(car_db1.getBrand());
                mCarView10.setText(car_db1.getColor()+ ", " + car_db1.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db1.getNumberPlate());

                mCarView2.setText(car_db2.getBrand());
                mCarView20.setText(car_db2.getColor()+ ", " + car_db2.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db2.getNumberPlate());

                mCarView3.setText(car_db3.getBrand());
                mCarView30.setText(car_db3.getColor()+ ", " + car_db3.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db3.getNumberPlate());

                mCarView4.setText(car_db4.getBrand());
                mCarView40.setText(car_db4.getColor()+ ", " + car_db4.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db4.getNumberPlate());

                if(car_db1.getBrand().equals("none") && car_db2.getBrand().equals("none") && car_db3.getBrand().equals("none") && car_db4.getBrand().equals("none")  )
                {
                    mAddCar1.setText("Add");
                    mAddCar2.setText("Add");
                    mAddCar3.setText("Add");
                    mAddCar4.setText("Add");

                    mDelCar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDelCar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDelCar3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car10layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    blueLine1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    car2layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    car20layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    blueLine2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    car3layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    car30layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    blueLine3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    car4layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    car40layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else if(car_db2.getBrand().equals("none") && car_db3.getBrand().equals("none") && car_db4.getBrand().equals("none") )
                {
                    mAddCar1.setText("Edit");
                    mAddCar2.setText("Add");
                    mAddCar3.setText("Add");
                    mAddCar4.setText("Add");

                    mDelCar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDelCar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDelCar3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car10layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blueLine1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    car2layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car20layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    blueLine2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    car3layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    car30layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    blueLine3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    car4layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    car40layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else if( car_db3.getBrand().equals("none") && car_db4.getBrand().equals("none") )
                {
                    mAddCar1.setText("Edit");
                    mAddCar2.setText("Edit");
                    mAddCar3.setText("Add");
                    mAddCar4.setText("Add");

                    mDelCar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mDelCar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDelCar3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car10layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blueLine1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    car2layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car20layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blueLine2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    car3layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car30layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    blueLine3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    car4layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    car40layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else if( car_db4.getBrand().equals("none"))
                {
                    mAddCar1.setText("Edit");
                    mAddCar2.setText("Edit");
                    mAddCar3.setText("Edit");
                    mAddCar4.setText("Add");

                    mDelCar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mDelCar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mDelCar3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car10layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blueLine1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    car2layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car20layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blueLine2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    car3layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car30layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blueLine3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    car4layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car40layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    mAddCar1.setText("Edit");
                    mAddCar2.setText("Edit");
                    mAddCar3.setText("Edit");
                    mAddCar4.setText("Edit");

                    mDelCar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mDelCar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mDelCar3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    car10layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blueLine1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    car2layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car20layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blueLine2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    car3layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car30layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    blueLine3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    car4layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    car40layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here you can either add a car (from a dialog alert box) or delete one (

```
mAddCar4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            car4 = chooseCar(mCarView4, "car4");

        }
    });
    mDelCar4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Save to database user informations
            firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String uID = firebaseUser.getUid();
            // set to none all data
            car4 = new Car("none", "none", "none", "none");
            mDatabase.child("cars").child(uID).child("car4").setValue(car4);
        }
    });
```

So far it was working good. 
[screenshot of this fragment in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPGDd.jpg)
But now I'm implementing a way to choose between one of the cars added in the previous fragment in a new one (fragment).

Here is how I print and choose the right car,

```
 package xxxxxxxxxxx.fragmentClasses;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

import xxxxxxxxxxx.Car;
import xxxxxxxxxxx.LoginActivity;
import xxxxxxxxxxx.MapActivity;
import xxxxxxxxxxx.R;

public class FragmentFuel extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    private Button buttonBook;
    private Button buttonEditCar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fuel, container, false);


        buttonBook =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_book);
        buttonBook.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonEditCar =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_edit_car);
        buttonEditCar.setOnClickListener(this);


        return view;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){

 //book with informations stocked
            case R.id.button_book :
                getActivity().finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
 // open a dialog box that shows differents car registered and made the user choose one
            case R.id.button_edit_car :

                mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

                final FirebaseUser FireUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(FireUser != null)
                {
                    String uid = FireUser.getUid().toString();
                    mDatabase.child("cars").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            final String[] listCars;
                            final Car car = new Car();
                            int j;

                            Car car_db1 = dataSnapshot.child("car1").getValue(Car.class);
                            Car car_db2 = dataSnapshot.child("car2").getValue(Car.class);
                            Car car_db3 = dataSnapshot.child("car3").getValue(Car.class);
                            Car car_db4 = dataSnapshot.child("car4").getValue(Car.class);

                            if (car_db1.getBrand().equals("none"))
                            {
                                listCars = new String[0];
                            }
                            else if (car_db2.getBrand().equals("none"))
                            {
                                listCars = new String[1];
                                listCars[0] = car_db1.getBrand() + ", " + car_db1.getColor() + ", " + car_db1.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db1.getNumberPlate();
                            }
                            else if (car_db3.getBrand().equals("none"))
                            {
                                listCars = new String[2];
                                listCars[0] = car_db1.getBrand() + ", " + car_db1.getColor() + ", " + car_db1.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db1.getNumberPlate();
                                listCars[1] = car_db2.getBrand() + ", " + car_db2.getColor() + ", " + car_db2.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db2.getNumberPlate();
                            }
                            else if (car_db4.getBrand().equals("none"))
                            {
                                listCars = new String[3];
                                listCars[0] = car_db1.getBrand() + ", " + car_db1.getColor() + ", " + car_db1.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db1.getNumberPlate();
                                listCars[1] = car_db2.getBrand() + ", " + car_db2.getColor() + ", " + car_db2.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db2.getNumberPlate();
                                listCars[2] = car_db3.getBrand() + ", " + car_db3.getColor() + ", " + car_db3.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db3.getNumberPlate();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                listCars = new String[4];
                                listCars[0] = car_db1.getBrand() + ", " + car_db1.getColor() + ", " + car_db1.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db1.getNumberPlate();
                                listCars[1] = car_db2.getBrand() + ", " + car_db2.getColor() + ", " + car_db2.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db2.getNumberPlate();
                                listCars[2] = car_db3.getBrand() + ", " + car_db3.getColor() + ", " + car_db3.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db3.getNumberPlate();
                                listCars[3] = car_db4.getBrand() + ", " + car_db4.getColor() + ", " + car_db4.getFuelType() + ", " + car_db4.getNumberPlate();
                            }

                            final AlertDialog myDialog1;
                            AlertDialog.Builder builderCar = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                            builderCar.setTitle("Choose your car");
                            builderCar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_car);
                            builderCar.setCancelable(false);
                            builderCar.setSingleChoiceItems(listCars, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                }
                            });
                            //Button to decide what to do next
                            builderCar.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    //nothing here, overrided later
                                }
                            });

                            myDialog1 = builderCar.create();
                            myDialog1.show();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            // Failed to read value
                        }

                    });
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

And it's working too, do nothing for now, but print the different car stocked in firebase and allow me to choose between one of them (ill implement that later).

[screenshot of the second fragment in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yHXt.jpg)

But here's my problem, when I go back to the first fragment, and that I delete or add a new car, the app crash. When I restart the app, everything have worked, the car is deleted or added. I think that problem is using the onDataChange on the second fragment, and not stopping it so it continue to read while the app interact with the DB. But I don't know how to do it.

Here is my logcat

```
    Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: xxxxxxxx, PID: 16656
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:113)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:291)
    at xxxxxxxx.fragmentClasses.FragmentFuel$1.onDataChange(FragmentFuel.java:121)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.tl.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.vg.zzHW(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.vm.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)

                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Event: crash
```

The bad thing is I cannot use the debugger while using onDataChange...

If someone have a clue it would really help me ! And sorry for my english ;)

Comment: To use the debugger in `onDataChange()`, set a breakpoint on the first statement **inside** `onDataChange()`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen not working for me :/

Comment: Given that your stack trace comes from within `onDataChange()`, the first statement in that method **is** being executed. From reading that stacktrace a bit further, it seems very likely that `getActivity()` is returning `null`.

Comment: The issue is where you are trying to create Alert Dialog in FuelFragment, I don't why "getActivity()" is becoming null.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was that, I've put the initialisation of the builderCar before the switch case with all the buttons and it works. Now I've to figure out how to block that onDataChange when I'm not currently on that fragment, cause it don't provoke crash, but it launch the Alert Dialog, anyway thanks !